# Insert page breaks or formfeed in python/c++/.jar programs executed on console

Tags: java, python, c++, console-application, page-break

How to insert **page breaks** or **formfeed** in python/c++/.jar programs executed on console? '\f' doesn't work as I know why, console does not recognize it. Can you show any other way please?

Comment: Standard Consoles have no understanding of pages. What are you really trying to do? Clear the screen?

Comment: Yes I want to clear the screen before the next output block is displayed. Can you please suggest an alternative if I am going in the wrong direction? I am developing a simple text-based console application. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In C, `\f` is the portable escape sequence to represent form-feed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Here's a break:\fAnd here's more text\n");
}
```

It's up to your terminal how it responds to that.  Most printers will start a new page; many on-screen terminals behave differently.

The same is true of the vertical tab sequence, `\v`.

If you want to find a terminal-specific escape code to clear the screen (assuming it has one; not all do), you'll need to look it up in a database such as terminfo.